# Cython caching with fused type

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython

I am trying to add fused type to [`scipy.stats.qmc._sobol.pyx`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/stats/_sobol.pyx).

The issue is that we are caching two matrices so that next runs of the functions would not require to load the matrices. We declare them as follow and use some global variable in a function to fill these or not.

```
cdef cnp.uint64_t poly[MAXDIM]
cdef cnp.uint64_t vinit[MAXDIM][MAXDEG]
```

If I try to use fused type instead of `cnp.uint64_t`, I have a compilation error. Indeed, Cython cannot decide on the type here.

The solution I thought about is to declare twice the matrices. One for `cnp.uint32_t` and one for `cnp.uint64_t`, then I can detect if I need the first or second set in each functions. But I am afraid it would increase the memory footprint. I thought about freeing one of the array but then if the user calls concurrently the matrices and ask for 32 and 64 bits then it might break.

```
cdef cnp.uint32_t poly_32[MAXDIM]
cdef cnp.uint32_t vinit_32[MAXDIM][MAXDEG]

cdef cnp.uint64_t poly_64[MAXDIM]
cdef cnp.uint64_t vinit_64[MAXDIM][MAXDEG]
```

Is there an alternative way to cache the matrices and use fused type? Matrices needs to either be `cnp.uint32_t` or `cnp.uint64_t`. Not that someone on a 64 bits architecture can ask to use the 32 bits of the functions, so I cannot really restrict 64 bits on 64 bits architecture.

---

Here is some more or less complete code to explain the whole logic in Cython and Python:

```
cdef cnp.uint64_t poly[MAXDIM]
cdef cnp.uint64_t vinit[MAXDIM][MAXDEG]

cdef bint is_initialized = False

def _initialize_direction_numbers():
    global is_initialized
    if not is_initialized:
        for i in range(...):
            poly[i] = ...
            vinit[i] = ...
        is_initialized = True

def _initialize_v(...):
    # use the cached values
    for i in range(...):
        ... = poly[i]
        ... = vinit[i]
```

In Python I have

```py
_initialize_direction_numbers()
_initialize_v(...)
```

Calling these 2 functions again would not load again the matrices because `is_initialized = True`.

Comment: Do you return these matrices to directly or just use them in calculations? If you just use them in calculations, is there a reason not to have one saved cached matrix?

Comment: I am no sure to understand your problem correctly but it seems you try to write either a 32-bit or a 64-bit matrix in a buffer. You can use memory view and `np.view` to wrap typed matrices in a buffer.

Comment: @DavidW the matrices are not returned, they "stay" in Cython. This way I can use the matrices within other functions. I have a function which is just filling up the matrices and it's only doing this once during the Python session thanks to a boolean. What do you mean about "one saved cached matrix"? To be clear I am loading from a file and not doing any extra processing, but this is too slow already, hence this in-memory caching.

Comment: @JérômeRichard how do you do this? And how the `np.view` would be typed? I will add more code to try explain a bit more.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you don't need both data types. Why not just have a 32 bit matrix, and use it in both the 32 bit and 64 bit calculations?

Comment: @DavidW I cannot just have 32 bit matrix because the maximal value in both matrix is 2^bits. I really need the unsigned version of both 32 and 64 bit integer.

Comment: We have a very large Monte Carlo simulation using Randomized Sobol points (latest SciPy) and the fastest solution I could find (since the points ARE NOT RANDOM) is to generate them, save to a 'npy' file, and read them from disk with a simple `np.load('sobol.npy', mmap_mode = 'r')` but how to do that in Cython I'm not sure, obviously you need the GIL to use a NumPy function

Comment: @Matt I am not sure what you are trying to do. Points are random if you use the scrambled version. Here I am talking about the direction numbers, so internals of the method. Feel free to open an issue on SciPy and ping me (tupui) if you have any comment/issue on how to use the method.

Comment: @tupui sorry I did not understand your purpose.  For us, it was using RQMC and we simply fixed the seed and saved out the sequence.  If you DO want them to be random with every call, then I suppose you are right, you need to regenerate the scrambling routine.

Comment: @Matt FYI I am the maintainer of the QMC submodule in SciPy. Here I want to add the possibility to change the number of bits which is used internally. I have a PR which allows to vary the number of bits, but it does not change the types internally. Here I am looking at how I can do this with fused types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do this with C arrays (i.e. `cdef cnp.uint64_t poly[MAXDIM]`). They have the disadvantages that:

- they use the memory whether or not they're actually initialized
- they're fairly likely to generate lack stack-allocated temporaries, which can cause errors (although the arrays themselves will not be stack allocated).

Instead I would probably use a `dict` of Numpy arrays. This doesn't actually involve using fused types.

```
_poly_dict = {}
_vinit_dict = {}

def get_poly(dtype):
    poly = _poly_dict.get(dtype)
    if not poly:
       _poly_dict[dtype] = np.empty(..., dtype=dtype)
       # ... initialize it
    return poly

# etc.
```

What you can then do is create memoryviews of these arrays (possibly within a fused function). Memoryviews are very quick to create since they only access existing memory. Something like

```
cdef fused int32or64:
   cnp.uint32_t
   cnp.uint64_t

def do_calculation(int32or64 user_value):
   # slightly awkward conversion from ctype to Numpy dtype 
   #  - if you have to do this often the use a helper function
   cdef int32or64[:] poly = get_poly(np.int32 if int32or64 is cnp.uint32_t else np.int64)
   # your calculation goes here...
```

---

As an aside, if you wanted to use a memoryview of a fused type in `get_poly` (for example, to initialize the array), it's often useful to add a dummy argument:

```
def get_poly(dtype, int32or64 dummy):
   ...
```

That lets you generate it as a fused function (so avoiding duplicating the code) even if it doesn't have a natural "input".

Comment: I think I got the idea. But I cannot compile `get_poly`. It says `_poly_dict` is undefined. Also in the function I don't get the inside of `get_poly`. Shouldn't it be `_poly_dict[dtype] = np.empty(..., dtype=dtype)`? (Can I pin you on GH once I make a PR? You are da-woods right?)

Comment: 1) `_poly_dict[dtype]` - yes it should be that. My mistake. 2) Yes you can ping me on github

Comment: All right now it compiles, thanks! I will give this a shot but sounds good.